# How would one go about drawing a Feynman diagram of color screening and anti-screening in QCD?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, gluons

Title really explains this one. I'm not sure how to put together a diagram of the lowest order for colour screening and anti-screening in QCD. Seems to be a lack of diagrams for this in the literature! Would anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At lowest order, color screening comes from virtual quark/antiquark pairs, just like charge screening comes from electron/positron pairs in QCD. The diagram/effect is also referred to as 'vacuum polarization' and is shown below.

[image]

Charge antiscreening comes from virtual gluon pairs; its diagram is below.

[image]